# How do I write the output of a SELECT SQL query to a file in Unix?

Tags: linux

I'm running a `SELECT` query against an SQL server.  I can see the output in front of me.  How do I arrange for that output to be written to a file, instead of to my screen?

Comment: Please be a little bit more descriptive. What exactly do you want to do? What tools do you use? What did you try? What was the problem?

Comment: What database are you talking about? Please [edit] your question to fill in all the details.

Answer (score 2):

Save your sql query in an file and then run this command.

`mysql -uusername -p dbname < input.sql > output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use this command.

> mysqldump -uusername -p dbname >db.sql